# Check equality of multiple elements in array

Tags: python

I'm new to Python from Matlab.

I want to create a new variable from a subset of an existing numpy array based on equality to some condition specified by a third numpy array, an ID in this case.

This works fine for one equality.

```
new_x = old_x[someID == 1]
```

But if I try to extend it several equalities at once it no longer works:

```
new_x = old_x[someID == 1:3]
```

Ideally I want to be able to choose many equalities, like:

```
new_x = old_x[someID == 1:3,7]
```

I could loop through each number I want to check but is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: What is `old_x`? A numpy array?

Comment: Yes, I've edited that in thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) + [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
import numpy as np

# for reproducible results
np.random.seed(42)

# toy data
old_x = np.random.randint(10, size=100)

# create new array by filtering on boolean mask
new_x = old_x[np.isin(old_x, np.r_[1:3,7])]

print(new_x)
```

**Output**

```
[7 2 7 7 7 2 1 7 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 7 2 1 7 1 1 1 7 7 1 7 7 7 7 2 7 2 2 7]
```

You could substitute `np.r_` by something like `[1, 2, 7]` and use it as below:

```
new_x = old_x[np.isin(old_x, [1, 2, 7])]
```

Additionally if the array is 1-dimensional you could use [`np.in1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d):

```
new_x = old_x[np.in1d(old_x, [1, 2, 7])]
print(new_x)
```

**Output** *(from in1d)*

```
[7 2 7 7 7 2 1 7 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 7 2 1 7 1 1 1 7 7 1 7 7 7 7 2 7 2 2 7]
```

Comment: Just retracted my `close` vote because of your answer. Good one! It made me better understand the question.

Comment: Using the np.r_  works perfectly thanks, seems like that might be useful little function. And thanks for generating toy data, I'll be sure to do that myself in fututre.